# Error installing opencv 2.4.3 on debian

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi

I am beginner to Raspberry Pi with debian OS.

When I install opencv-2.4.3 with `"sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf"` I got this error:

```
"sudo: gedit:command not found"
```

Then I was trying to install "gedit" but it failed with this error:

```
"The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
gedit : Depends: libpeas-1.0-0 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed 
    Depends: gir1.2-peas-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: This is all but an OpenCV installation error :) You should change the title.

Comment: What command did you use to install ``gedit``?

Answer (score 0):

Just install aptitude that will resolve dependencies for you.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install gedit
```

Moreover to edit your file you can also use vim or nano.

Regards